# How come my mesh moves incorrectly?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting

Put my neck on the line in an animation project at work and I’ve hit a wall.

I’ve meshed everything. I’ve set up the bones and the mesh has all the transformations applied. I’ve removed weight from all the bone except the parent bones and have applied with weights using the weight brush tool. However the mesh seems to deform really weird?

Anyone got any ideas?

Here's the mesh and armature appended from the original file
https://filebin.net/2nvq8teg31417o4s/Example.blend?t=wfl37dqp

[image: https://i.paste.pics/8GB6N.png]
[image]

Comment: Your weigths are wrong. In this case one bone have to affect one area only. In your file every bone affects its children's areas too.